# How to check the type of a AnyObject cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableView` and I implemented a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to it. When you long press a cell, it calls a function called `handleLongPress`.

```
func handleLongPress(sender:AnyObject){

}
```

The problem is, there are several types of `UITableViewCells` in my `UITableView` so I need to know what kind of `cell` is long clicked. An example of my custom cell:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ivProfile: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tvName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tvEmail: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I tried this:

```
if sender is ProfileTableViewCell{
            print("Long Clicked!")
        }
```

And this:

```
if let mType = sender as? ProfileTableViewCell{
            print("Long Clicked!")
        }
```

None of these work. How do I check the type of cell ?

Edit: This is how assign the gesture recognizer:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell

longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ProfileTableViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
longPress.delaysTouchesBegan = true
longPress.delegate = self
cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

Comment: How are you assigning the gesture recognizer?

Comment: I added as edit, check it out.

Comment: Okay, and by the way, if you're only expecting subclasses of `UITableViewCell` to be the sender, you can change `sender:AnyObject` to `sender: UITableViewCell`

Comment: Ok, I will change it. However, will it help solving my issue ? If so, how?

Comment: Probably not, just thought I'd mention it. I'm testing a few things, just hold on for a sec.

Comment: what are you going to do as a result of the long press ?

Comment: @Wain Gonna open up a dialog to make a webservice call.

Comment: @dzk Okay, when I do print(sender), This is the output, it might be helpful somehow: <UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0x7979d0c0; state = Began; delaysTouchesBegan = YES; view = <MyProject.ProfileTableViewCell 0x7a3ffc00>; target= <(action=handleLongPress:, target=<MyProject.ProfileTableViewController 0x7ac661b0>)>>

Comment: It's the gesture recogniser that's the sender, not your cell. You need to check which view it's embedded in

Comment: @dirkgroten You're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So everything else seems fine, just change your handler as such:

```
func handleLongPress(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.view {
    case is ProfileTableViewCell: print("Is a ProfileTableViewCell")
    default: print("Is not.")
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. Sometimes it does not detect the long press but I will look into it. Thanks!